# Laravel fetch data by groupBy

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, fetch

[image]

I need to retrieve all this data, as well as I, need to get only one row of the repeated data in column'gallery_name'.

Output => 2020 and name column, 2013 and name column only
how can get

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Mehod**

```
$text = DB::table('text')
            ->groupBy('check_id')
            ->having('check_id', '>', 100)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

While you need to retrieve all data grouped by **gallery_name**, you can do the following:

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')->get();
$grouped = $data->groupBy('gallery_name');
```

Now, you can iterate and do what you need.